# Rails 3, has_many :through and the << operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Converting an app to Rails 3. Ran into this missing syntactic sugar.

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
end
```

I can no longer do this in Rails 3:

```
$ group = Group.first
$ user = User.first
$ group.users << user
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Column 'user_id' cannot 
be null: INSERT INTO `memberships` (`admin`, `created_at`, 
`group_id`, `leader`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES 
(0, '2010-11-03 18:31:33', 5, 0, '2010-11-03 18:31:33', NULL)
```

Where did `<<` go? Has it been replaced by something?

Answer (score 0):

The << method is there. The error is from MySQL. Did you actually do this with existing records?

Answer (score 0):

Key missing information. I had an initializer that did the following to force a protective state on my models:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:attr_accessible, nil)
```

In this case the Membership class actually needs to look like this:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :user_id, :group_id
end
```

Basically, Rails internals must not have the power to access protected attributes that they used to have prior to Rails 3.